# Переадресация со старых ссылок на новые, индексация новых ссылок kohana

Tags: seo, php, kohana

**Здравствуйте**, появился вопрос, как быть с тем что на сайте есть и старые ссылки и новые, сделал чпу небольшое, так вот  по старым ссылкам информация проиндексирована, по новым удобным ссылкам не проиндексировано, я собираюсь по новым ссылкам продвигать, как мне быть? Посоветуйте как лучше сделать, закрыть старые ссылки и сделать пере адресацию на новые?

**Обновление**

```
/application
bootstrap.php
```

У меня там роут стоит

```
 Route::set('contacts', 'contacts')   
 ->defaults(array( 
         'directory'  => 'index', 
         'controller' => 'page', 
         'action'     => 'contacts', 
 ));
```

Как я старые ссылки удалю? У меня kohana. На главной старнице сайта я заменил ссылки на новые.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать со старых ссылок 301 редирект на новые. Через несколько месяцев старые можно будет удалить.

**Обновление**

В `.htaccess` в корне написать:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.+) http://site.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Веб-сервер apache? Напиши в .htaccess RewriteRule и не трогай скрипты.

Comment: как правильно напсать

была ссылка сайт.ru/page/contacts
я сделал через роутер сайт.ru/contacts

щас по обеем ссылкам можно зайти на сайт.
но проиндексированная информация на старой ссылке.
так же есть другие страницы в которых я убрал page

Comment: Обновил ответ